# update sql oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone help to update a column in Oracle SQL with the VARCHAR2 format?
All the methods do not work.
Thank you in advance!

```
UPDATE CYCLESTATUS SET SESSIONINSTANCEID = 'P27SEK0404202201';
```

'P27SEK'+current date(04042022)+'01'

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use || for concatenation and if you want the current date you can use `TO_CHAR` to extract the date string in specific format:

```
'P27SEK'|| TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DDMMYYYY')||'01'
```